# How to add Environment Variables to existing properties in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

In a Spring Boot application there are the following properties set within a Yaml file:

```yaml
application:
  credentials:
    - key: "admin"
      secret: "42"
    - key: "user"
      secret: "1234"
```

I now want to add a credential via `Environment` and doing like that will function partially:

```
APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_0_KEY=elvis
APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_0_SECRET=aloha
```

The problem with this approach is, that the existing properties get wiped, since I have to specify an array index with the environment variables.

How can I set up the yaml file and provide the env-variables, so that I can dynamically add credentials without deleting the existing ones and without knowing in advance, if and how many additional credentials will be used?